# Custom right click menu for a WebView inside an NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, webview, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

I have a WebView embedded in an NSStatusItem, and I want to display an NSMenu that I've built in Interface Builder when the user right clicks on the WebView / NSStatusItem. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: a `WebView` inside an `NSStatusItem`?? That sounds *extremely* unconventional...

Comment: Haha, I know, but I have my reasons :)

Answer (score 5):

You can assign an object as the web view's WebUIDelegate and implement this delegate method:

```
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
```

where you can return array with custom created menu items.

Answer (score -2):

```
[statusItem setMenu:menu];
```

or for right click, make a new subclass of nsview. In your subclass add the method:

```
(void)rightMouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

Then you can set the view to the statusItem `[statusItem setView:view]`;

Comment: Ah didn't see this. Just make a new subclass of nsview. In your subclass add the method: -(void)rightMouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent. Then you can set the view to the statusItem [statusItem setView:view];